# Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе какого-то события из списка, менялся код таймера (сколько остается дней до этого события)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Например: Человек выбрал их списка событие 'Лето', тогда у него появляется таймер отсчета времени до 1 июня; человек вновь выбирает из списка событие, но уже другое '8 марта', тогда старый таймер удаляется, а появляется новый, показывающий сколько осталось дней до этого события (8 марта). Если что-то непонятно, обязательно задавайте вопрос в комментариях. Постараюсь объяснить то, что вы не поняли.**

```
 <!-- Показывается 1 таймер отсчета (до 1 июня): -->

<div class="timer" id="timer">
    <div class="timer__items">
      <div class="timer__item timer__days">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__hours">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__minutes">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__seconds">00</div>
    </div>
  </div> 


  <!-- Показывается 2 таймер отсчета (до 8 марта): -->

  <div class="timer__two" id="timer__two">
    <div class="timer__items__two">
      <div class="timer__item__two days__two">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item__two hours__two">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item__two minutes__two">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item__two seconds__two">00</div>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <!-- Показывается 3 таймер (до 1 сентября): -->

  <div class="timer__three" id="timer__three">
    <div class="timer__items__three">
      <div class="timer__item__three days__three">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item__three hours__three">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item__three minutes__three">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item__three seconds__three">00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
<style>
    .timer__two{
        display: none;
    }
    .timer__three{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

---

```
<!-- Список, из которого пользователь выбирает событие, чтобы узнать сколько остается дней до него: -->

  <select name="cities" id="select">
    <option value="Summer">Лето</option>
    <option value="Spring">8 марта</option>
    <option value="Autumn">1 сентября</option>
  </select>
  
  <button id="btn">Подсчитать</button>
```

---

```
<!-- Это код таймера (в данном случае отсчитывающий до 1 июня): -->
<!-- Нужно сделать так, чтобы в этом скрипте менялась переменная до какого числа нужно вести отсчет времени (сколько дней осталось)-->
<!-- Например: если человек выбрал из событий 8 марта, то меняется код, так, чтобы велся отсчет до 8 марта, а не до какого-то другого события -->

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // конечная дата
      const deadline = new Date(2022, 05, 01);
      // id таймера
      let timerId = null;
      // склонение числительных
      function declensionNum(num, words) {
        return words[(num % 100 > 4 && num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][(num % 10 < 5) ? num % 10 : 5]];
      }
      // вычисляем разницу дат и устанавливаем оставшееся времени в качестве содержимого элементов
      function countdownTimer() {
        const diff = deadline - new Date();
        if (diff <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timerId);
        }
        const days = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) : 0;
        const hours = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 : 0;
        const minutes = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60 : 0;
        const seconds = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60 : 0;
        $days.textContent = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
        $hours.textContent = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
        $minutes.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        $seconds.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        $days.dataset.title = declensionNum(days, ['день', 'дня', 'дней']);
        $hours.dataset.title = declensionNum(hours, ['час', 'часа', 'часов']);
        $minutes.dataset.title = declensionNum(minutes, ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']);
        $seconds.dataset.title = declensionNum(seconds, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']);
      }
      // получаем элементы, содержащие компоненты даты
      const $days = document.querySelector('.timer__days');
      const $hours = document.querySelector('.timer__hours');
      const $minutes = document.querySelector('.timer__minutes');
      const $seconds = document.querySelector('.timer__seconds');
      // вызываем функцию countdownTimer
      countdownTimer();
      // вызываем функцию countdownTimer каждую секунду
      timerId = setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000);
    });
  </script>

  
  <script>
    const cities = document.getElementById('select');
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    const time_one = document.getElementById('timer');
    const time_two = document.getElementById('timer__two');
    const time_three = document.getElementById('timer__three');
  
// Условия, по которым появляется нужный таймер для отсчета времени до нужного события:

    btn.onclick = event => {
      let checkedCityText = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].text;
      if (checkedCityText == 'Лето') {
        time_one.style.display = 'block';
        time_two.style.display = 'none';
        time_three.style.display = 'none';
      }
      if (checkedCityText == '8 марта') {
        time_one.style.display = 'none';
        time_two.style.display = 'block';
        time_three.style.display = 'none';
      }
      if (checkedCityText == '1 сентября') {
        time_one.style.display = 'none';
        time_two.style.display = 'none';
        time_three.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас `deadline` константа объявленная в функции. От того у вас сложности с тем, чтобы обновить значение. Просто вынесите её в более доступную область видимости, да даже в глобальный объект, и сделайте изменяемой. В функцию `counterTime` передавайте как аргумент.

Та же проблема с анонимной функцией объявленной в обработчике события `DOMContentLoaded` — Вы просто не можете использовать её множество раз, а также передавать аргументы.

Вариант с тем, чтобы обновлять таймер при смене события:

1. Вынесите анонимную функцию во вне, а внутри DOMContentLoaded вызывайте её.
2. Вместо константного значения `new Date(2022, 05, 01)` создайте и используйте аргумент, например, `date`
3. Вызывайте функцию, которую вынесли на этапе 1 каждый раз, когда пользователь меняет "событие"
4. Очищайте предыдущий таймер

Вариант через изменение `deadline`:

1. Вынести её и сделать изменяемой
2. При каждом `countdownTimer()` высчитывайте diff основываясь на текущем значении `deadline`

```js
function countdownTimer() {
        const diff = globalThis.deadline - new Date();
        if (diff <= 0) {
          // Если останавливать интервал, то при окончании одного события таймер остановиться и для других
          return;
        }
        const days = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) : 0;
        const hours = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 : 0;
        const minutes = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60 : 0;
        const seconds = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60 : 0;
        $days.textContent = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
        $hours.textContent = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
        $minutes.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        $seconds.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        $days.dataset.title = declensionNum(days, ['день', 'дня', 'дней']);
        $hours.dataset.title = declensionNum(hours, ['час', 'часа', 'часов']);
        $minutes.dataset.title = declensionNum(minutes, ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']);
        $seconds.dataset.title = declensionNum(seconds, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']);
      }
```

```js
btn.onclick = event => {
      let checkedCityText = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].text;
      if (checkedCityText == 'Лето') {
        time_one.style.display = 'block';
        time_two.style.display = 'none';
        time_three.style.display = 'none';
        globalThis.deadline = new Date (<дата>);
      }
      if (checkedCityText == '8 марта') {
        time_one.style.display = 'none';
        time_two.style.display = 'block';
        time_three.style.display = 'none';
        globalThis.deadline = new Date (<дата>);
      }
      if (checkedCityText == '1 сентября') {
        time_one.style.display = 'none';
        time_two.style.display = 'none';
        time_three.style.display = 'block';
        globalThis.deadline = new Date (<дата>);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Почему-то не работает

Comment: Меняется текст только первого таймера. Также в начале кода я забыл указать globalThis.deadline = new Date(<дата>) как значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Всё равно не работает :(

Comment: Можете пожалуйста полностью код написать, может я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Основное, что я сделал — это заменил `diff = deadline - new Date()` на `globalThis.deadline`, что решало вашу проблему

Все остальное в демонстративных целях, чтобы "работало":

- Вынес смену таймера в отдельную функцию `setDeadline`
- Оставил всего один таймер вместо
- Изменил метку по умолчанию с 2022, 05, 01 т.к. эта дата прошла и таймер отображал 0.00.00

```html
<div class="timer" id="timer">
    <!-- Не знаю имели ли смысл несколько таймеров.  -->
    <div class="timer__items">
      <div class="timer__item timer__days">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__hours">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__minutes">00</div>
      <div class="timer__item timer__seconds">00</div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <style>
    /* Для демонстрации того, как по необходимости для каждого таймера указывать особый стиль */
    .timer[data-style="summer"] {
      background: rgba(238, 193, 156, 0.4);
    }

    .timer[data-style="spring"] {
      background: rgb(241, 194, 218, 0.4);
    }

    .timer[data-style="autumn"] {
      background: rgb(110, 81, 112, 0.4);
    }
</style>


  <select name="cities" id="select">
    <option value="Summer">Лето</option>
    <option value="Spring">8 марта</option>
    <option value="Autumn">1 сентября</option>
  </select>

  <button id="btn">Подсчитать</button>


  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      setDeadline("Лето");
      // id таймера
      let timerId = null;
      // склонение числительных
      function declensionNum(num, words) {
        return words[(num % 100 > 4 && num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][(num % 10 < 5) ? num % 10 : 5]];
      }
      // вычисляем разницу дат и устанавливаем оставшееся времени в качестве содержимого элементов
      function countdownTimer() {
        const diff = globalThis.deadline - new Date();
        if (diff <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timerId);
        }
        const days = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) : 0;
        const hours = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 : 0;
        const minutes = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60 : 0;
        const seconds = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60 : 0;
        $days.textContent = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
        $hours.textContent = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
        $minutes.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        $seconds.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        $days.dataset.title = declensionNum(days, ['день', 'дня', 'дней']);
        $hours.dataset.title = declensionNum(hours, ['час', 'часа', 'часов']);
        $minutes.dataset.title = declensionNum(minutes, ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']);
        $seconds.dataset.title = declensionNum(seconds, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']);
      }
      // получаем элементы, содержащие компоненты даты
      const $days = document.querySelector('.timer__days');
      const $hours = document.querySelector('.timer__hours');
      const $minutes = document.querySelector('.timer__minutes');
      const $seconds = document.querySelector('.timer__seconds');
      // вызываем функцию countdownTimer
      countdownTimer();
      // вызываем функцию countdownTimer каждую секунду
      timerId = setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000);
    });
  </script>


  <script>
    const cities = document.getElementById('select');
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    const time_one = document.getElementById('timer');

// Условия, по которым появляется нужный таймер для отсчета времени до нужного события:

    btn.onclick = event => {
      let checkedCityText = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].text;
      // Я вынес в отдельную функцию, чтобы её можно было вызвать другими способами, например при загрузке страницы
      setDeadline(checkedCityText);
    }

    function setDeadline(id){
      if (id == 'Лето') {
        time_one.setAttribute("data-style", "summer");
        globalThis.deadline = new Date(2023, 06, 01);
      }
      if (id == '8 марта') {
        time_one.setAttribute("data-style", "spring");
        globalThis.deadline = new Date(2023, 03, 08);
      }
      if (id == '1 сентября') {
        time_one.setAttribute("data-style", "autumn");
        globalThis.deadline = new Date(2023, 09, 01);
      }


    }
  </script>
```